# NSIS: how to uncompress 7zip archive

Tags: compression, nsis

I want to make an auto-extract archive with 7zip, i'am able to do it but in the 7zip archive i have only pdf or doc files, so at the auto-extract process can launch an exe at the end of extract process.

I was looking to use NSIS to do it with Nsis7z plug-in, but i need an example to do it. Do-you have an example of nsi file somewhere to do it ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

It's basically, what it says on the [plug-in Wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Nsis7z_plug-in):

```
# Init temporary folder $PLUGINSDIR
InitPluginsDir

# Include 7-zip archive
SetOutPath $PLUGINSDIR
ReserveFile "myArchive.7z"

# Extract archive
Nsis7z::Extract "$PLUGINSDIR\myArchive.7z"
Delete "$PLUGINSDIR\myArchive.7z"
```

The extracted files are now located in [`$PLUGINSDIR`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Variables/PLUGINSDIR.md). Also note that I used [`ReserveFile`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/ReserveFile.md) instead of [`File`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/File.md), since we don't want recompress the archive.

Comment: I'm having several issues with this answer. Where is $PLUGINSDIR exactly and how do I tell it to really extract the files to somewhere else when a user runs the installer? And when I use ReserveFile, the .7z is never placed inside the setup file... but that seems like what I want.

Comment: The `$PLUGINSDIR` is a randomly named folder inside your Temporary Files directory, usually named *nsXXX.tmp* (XXX is a random string). Since it's a random name, you can use `$PLUGINSDIR` to reference it.